# Moving grub from one disk to another

Tags: 13.04, grub2, 13.10

I have 13.04 installed on my hard drive in my laptop, I now also have 13.10 on an SSD in the same machine.

At the moment to boot 13.10 I have to set in bios to boot my hard drive (which is not the disk 13.10 is on) which I guess launches grub from my hd and then I can select to launch Ubuntu (which launches 13.10) or Ubuntu 13.04 - both work.

My question is - how do I move grub from the hd to the SSD so in future if my hd fails my instal won't? I don't really need the 13.04 install to keep working although it would be handy.

Many thanks.

Comment: go with sdb and never with sdbxy

Answer (score 7):

**Reinstalling GRUB 2 from a Working System**

If Ubuntu is operating normally, boot into the working installation and run the following command from a terminal.

X is the drive (letter) on which you want GRUB to write the boot information.**OP you placed your SSD /dev/ in the command. If you want to know that , after connecting your SSD to Ubuntu machine type `df -h` there you can find your SSD /dev/ code.**

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX  # Example: sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

This will rewrite the MBR information to point to the current installation and rewrite some GRUB 2 files (which are already working). Since it isn't done during execution of the previous command, running sudo update-grub after the install will ensure GRUB 2's menu is up-to-date.

Comment: It's the sudo fdisk -l command to list your /dev/sdx device.

Comment: Thanks :) my fdisk outputs that my ssd which I want grub on is:

Disk /dev/sdb: 120.0 GB

The table for it looks like:

Device Boot         Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2          501758   234440703   116969473    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5          501760   234440703   116969472   8e  Linux LVM

Should I run th egrub command against sdb or sdb1 ?

Comment: run the command for sdb and not recommended for sdbXY

Comment: I had to switch my bootloader (GRUB) from a dying primary hard disk (sda) to secondary hard disk (Sdb).   ran "sudo grub-install /dev/sdb" and changed BIOS boot sequence to boot from secondary hard disk first.  Worked like a charm.

Comment: @nicoX I think the easiest and fastest command to find that is `lsblk`.

Comment: What if I have +two windows partitions? will it move them as Well? Also if one windows in the main drive alongside with ubuntu and the another windows is completely in other small (220 GB) drive ? will this work , or it will screw it up?  :)

Answer (score 0):

another option might be to clone the 13.04 with Clonezilla, then restore using Clonezilla to the SSD drive using a CZ boot stick/CD/DVD. I wont guarantee it but it would probably work. you might get the Ubuntu logo and top left corner says press S to continue, that requires the fstab file to be modified to reflect the new drive.
https://clonezilla.org/

Answer (score 0):

On pepperment "xubuntu" the simple copy of grub will not work when you switch boot from Bios, as sdb which has the grub copy became sda and many error messages then stop, however switching back will work with some error messages of files not found at where expected.