# Boot Debian from an external SSD drive

Tags: 16.04, boot, ssd, debian

Ubuntu 16.04LTS on notebook and some Debian version on an external USB SSD drive. What should be configured in Ubuntu to boot Debian from the SSD drive?

Comment: Are both Ubuntu 16.04 and Debian (SSD) installed in UEFI?

Comment: it seems not. I don't know. Is this important?

Comment: Yes, it's very important.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a choice to make. You have two devices, one is not even permanently attached to your laptop. 
Choice one would be to initiate the bios boot menu, select the drive ,either the internal with Ubuntu or the SSD with Debian. 
Your second choice should be to reinstall Grub on your debian system. By pointing grub to the internal disk it will create an entry in your already existing grub menu.
Moving a grub entry is not trivial, so I'd save your bootsection with dd before trying. 
Look here [Moving grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364914/moving-grub-from-one-disk-to-another) for more information.